# Find the probability such that picking a function $f(1)f(2)f(3)=6$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions

> Let $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ find the probability such that picking a function formed with these sets it verifies this equality $f(1)f(2)f(3)=6.$

What I thought:

We have 3 cases for $f(1)=\{1,2,3\}$ so $f(1)$ can be equal to $1$, $2$ or $3$.

If $f(1)=1\implies f(2)=\{2,3\}$ then if $f(2) = 2\implies f(3)=3$ and so on.. I counted $6$ possible combinations then the probability is $P=\frac {no. favorable}{no.possible}$ then $no.favorable=6$ and $no.possible=3^4=81$. Then $P=\frac 2{29}$. But it is not correct and I don't see where I'm wrong

Comment: $$\frac{6}{3^3} = \frac{2}{9}$$ since $f(4)$ is not relevant.

Comment: @MrRipstein: It doesn't satisfy the equality? Are you perhaps missing that $f(4)$ isn't in the equality?

Comment: @Crostul So $f(4)$ can actually not exist?

Comment: @Chris Oh right, I missread the argument

Comment: @C.Cristi No, the notation $f: \{1,2,3,4 \} \rightarrow \{1,2,3 \}$ implies that $f(4)$ must exist and must equal $1$, $2$ or $3$, but just that in this case we don't really care what the value of $f(4)$ is, hence the probability is $$\frac{3!}{3^3} = \frac{6}{3^3} = \frac 29$$